# Deleting rows if cells contain certain words (Syntax Error)

Tags: excel, vba, syntax-error, cell

I have data in which there is a list of value of expors per each country. I'll work with the countries whose population is greater than 3.5 million. So, I need to get rid of those who are not. Here is the code I got:

```
Sub Loop_Example()
    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'We use the ActiveSheet but you can replace this with
    'Sheets("MySheet")if you want
    With ActiveSheet

        'We select the sheet so we can change the window view
        .Select

        'If you are in Page Break Preview Or Page Layout view go
        'back to normal view, we do this for speed
        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

        'Turn off Page Breaks, we do this for speed
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False

        'Set the first and last row to loop through
        Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
        Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

        'We loop from Lastrow to Firstrow (bottom to top)
        For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

            'We check the values in the A column in this example
            With .Cells(Lrow, "J")

                If Not IsError(.Value) Then

                    Select Case .Value


         Case Is = "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Mongolia", "Armenia", "Jamaica", "Qatar", "Albania", "Puerto Rico", "Lithuania", "Namibia", "Gambia", "Botswana", "Gabon", "Lesotho", "TFYR of Macedonia", "Slovenia", "Guinea-Bissau", "Latvia", "Bahrain", "Equatorial", "Guinea", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Estonia", "Timor-Leste", "Mauritius", "Cyprus", "Eswatini", "Djibouti", "Fiji", "Réunion Comoros", Guyana Bhutan Solomon Islands Macao Montenegro Luxembourg Western Sahara Suriname Cabo Verde Maldives Malta Brunei "Guadeloupe", "Belize", "Bahamas", "Martinique", "Iceland", "Vanuatu", "French Guiana", "Barbados", "New Caledonia", "French Polynesia", "Mayotte", "Sao Tome & Principe Samoa", "Saint Lucia Channel Islands", "Guam", "Curaçao", "Kiribati", "FS Micronesia", "Grenada", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Aruba", "Tonga", "U.S. Virgin Islands","Seychelles", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Isle of Man", "Andorra", "Dominica", "Cayman Islands", "Bermuda", "Marshall Islands", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Greenland",
     "American Samoa", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Faeroe Islands", "Sint Maarten", "Monaco", "Turks and Caicos", "Saint Martin", "Liechtenstein", "San Marino", "Gibraltar", "British Virgin Islands", "Caribbean Netherlands", "Palau", "Cook Islands", "Anguilla", "Tuvalu", "Wallis & Futuna", "Nauru", "Saint Barthelemy", "Saint Helena", "Saint Pierre & Miquelon", "Montserrat", "Falkland Islands", "Niue", "Tokelau", "Holy See", "Rep. of Moldova", "Macedonia", "Neth. Antilles", "EU", "Asia n.i.e.": .EntireRow.Delete
            End Select
                    'This will delete each row with the countries written above
                    'in Column A, case sensitive.

                End If

            End With

        Next Lrow

    End With

    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub
```

Is it possible for me look for the countries listed above (I know it is many)? How am I'm supposed to edit that part to avoid getting "Syntax Error". Sorry, I'm new to VBA.

Comment: Forget about `Select Case`. Put all the countries in a column on your worksheet (it could be a hidden one and you might add different spellings for some countries). Then apply Application.Match of `Find` to the range and if the item is found it gets deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

Rather than deleting a row one by one, collecting the row and storing it in the range object, then deleting the range object at once will speed up execution.

```
Sub Loop_Example()
    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim rngU As Range
    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'We use the ActiveSheet but you can replace this with
    'Sheets("MySheet")if you want
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    'With ActiveSheet
    With Ws
        .Activate
        'If you are in Page Break Preview Or Page Layout view go
        'back to normal view, we do this for speed
        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

        'Turn off Page Breaks, we do this for speed
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False

        'Set the first and last row to loop through
        Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
        Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

        'We loop from Lastrow to Firstrow (bottom to top)
        For Lrow = Firstrow To Lastrow Step 1

            'We check the values in the A column in this example
            With .Cells(Lrow, "J")

                If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                    Select Case .Value
                    Case Is = "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Mongolia", "Armenia", "Jamaica", "Qatar", "Albania", "Puerto Rico", "Lithuania", _
                              "Namibia", "Gambia", "Botswana", "Gabon", "Lesotho", "TFYR of Macedonia", "Slovenia", "Guinea-Bissau", _
                              "Latvia", "Bahrain", "Equatorial", "Guinea", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Estonia", "Timor-Leste", "Mauritius", _
                              "Cyprus", "Eswatini", "Djibouti", "Fiji", "Reunion Comoros", "Guyana", "Bhutan", "Solomon Islands", "Macao", _
                              "Montenegro", "Luxembourg", "Western Sahara", "Suriname", "Cabo", "Verde", "Maldives", "Malta", "Brunei", _
                              "Guadeloupe", "Belize", "Bahamas", "Martinique", "Iceland", "Vanuatu", "French Guiana", "Barbados", "New Caledonia", _
                              "French Polynesia", "Mayotte", "Sao Tome & Principe Samoa", "Saint Lucia Channel Islands", "Guam", "Curacao", "Kiribati", _
                              "FS Micronesia", "Grenada", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Aruba", "Tonga", "U.S. Virgin Islands", "Seychelles", _
                              "Antigua and Barbuda", "Isle of Man", "Andorra", "Dominica", "Cayman Islands", "Bermuda", "Marshall Islands", _
                              "Northern Mariana Islands", "Greenland", "American Samoa", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Faeroe Islands", "Sint Maarten", _
                              "Monaco", "Turks and Caicos", "Saint Martin", "Liechtenstein", "San Marino", "Gibraltar", "British Virgin Islands", _
                              "Caribbean Netherlands", "Palau", "Cook Islands", "Anguilla", "Tuvalu", "Wallis & Futuna", "Nauru", "Saint Barthelemy", _
                              "Saint Helena", "Saint Pierre & Miquelon", "Montserrat", "Falkland Islands", "Niue", "Tokelau", "Holy See", "Rep. of Moldova", _
                              "Macedonia", "Neth. Antilles", "EU", "Asia n.i.e."
                            If rngU Is Nothing Then
                                Set rngU = Ws.Range("a" & Lrow)
                            Else
                                Set rngU = Union(rngU, Ws.Range("a" & Lrow))
                            End If
                    End Select
                End If
            End With
        Next Lrow
    End With

    'rngU is all Countries that meet the conditions

    If rngU Is Nothing Then
    Else
        rngU.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using Line Breaks

You got a little bit tired from Guyana to Brunei.

**Relevant Snippet (A Quick Fix)**

```
'We loop from Lastrow to Firstrow (bottom to top)
For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

    'We check the values in the A column in this example
    With .Cells(Lrow, "J")

        If Not IsError(.Value) Then

            Select Case .Value
                Case "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Mongolia", "Armenia", "Jamaica", "Qatar", "Albania", "Puerto Rico", "Lithuania", _
                  "Namibia", "Gambia", "Botswana", "Gabon", "Lesotho", "TFYR of Macedonia", "Slovenia", "Guinea-Bissau", "Latvia", _
                  "Bahrain", "Equatorial", "Guinea", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Estonia", "Timor-Leste", "Mauritius", "Cyprus", _
                  "Eswatini", "Djibouti", "Fiji", "Réunion Comoros", "Guyana", "Bhutan", "Solomon Islands", "Macao", "Montenegro", _
                  "Luxembourg", "Western Sahara", "Suriname", "Cabo Verde", "Maldives", "Malta", "Brunei", "Guadeloupe", "Belize", _
                  "Bahamas", "Martinique", "Iceland", "Vanuatu", "French Guiana", "Barbados", "New Caledonia", "French Polynesia", _
                  "Mayotte", "Sao Tome & Principe Samoa", "Saint Lucia Channel Islands", "Guam", "Curaçao", "Kiribati", _
                  "FS Micronesia", "Grenada", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Aruba", "Tonga", "U.S. Virgin Islands", _
                  "Seychelles", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Isle of Man", "Andorra", "Dominica", "Cayman Islands", "Bermuda", _
                  "Marshall Islands", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Greenland", "American Samoa", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", _
                  "Faeroe Islands", "Sint Maarten", "Monaco", "Turks and Caicos", "Saint Martin", "Liechtenstein", "San Marino", _
                  "Gibraltar", "British Virgin Islands", "Caribbean Netherlands", "Palau", "Cook Islands", "Anguilla", "Tuvalu", _
                  "Wallis & Futuna", "Nauru", "Saint Barthelemy", "Saint Helena", "Saint Pierre & Miquelon", "Montserrat", _
                  "Falkland Islands", "Niue", "Tokelau", "Holy See", "Rep. of Moldova", "Macedonia", "Neth. Antilles", "EU", _
                  "Asia n.i.e."
                    .EntireRow.Delete
            End Select
            'This will delete each row with the countries written above
            'in Column A, case sensitive.

        End If

    End With

Next Lrow
```

**Introducing an Array (A Better Solution)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Loop_Example()

    Dim LessPop As Variant
    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long

    LessPop = Array("Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Mongolia", "Armenia", "Jamaica", "Qatar", "Albania", "Puerto Rico", "Lithuania", _
      "Namibia", "Gambia", "Botswana", "Gabon", "Lesotho", "TFYR of Macedonia", "Slovenia", "Guinea-Bissau", "Latvia", _
      "Bahrain", "Equatorial", "Guinea", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Estonia", "Timor-Leste", "Mauritius", "Cyprus", _
      "Eswatini", "Djibouti", "Fiji", "Réunion Comoros", "Guyana", "Bhutan", "Solomon Islands", "Macao", "Montenegro", _
      "Luxembourg", "Western Sahara", "Suriname", "Cabo Verde", "Maldives", "Malta", "Brunei", "Guadeloupe", "Belize", _
      "Bahamas", "Martinique", "Iceland", "Vanuatu", "French Guiana", "Barbados", "New Caledonia", "French Polynesia", _
      "Mayotte", "Sao Tome & Principe Samoa", "Saint Lucia Channel Islands", "Guam", "Curaçao", "Kiribati", _
      "FS Micronesia", "Grenada", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Aruba", "Tonga", "U.S. Virgin Islands", _
      "Seychelles", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Isle of Man", "Andorra", "Dominica", "Cayman Islands", "Bermuda", _
      "Marshall Islands", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Greenland", "American Samoa", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", _
      "Faeroe Islands", "Sint Maarten", "Monaco", "Turks and Caicos", "Saint Martin", "Liechtenstein", "San Marino", _
      "Gibraltar", "British Virgin Islands", "Caribbean Netherlands", "Palau", "Cook Islands", "Anguilla", "Tuvalu", _
      "Wallis & Futuna", "Nauru", "Saint Barthelemy", "Saint Helena", "Saint Pierre & Miquelon", "Montserrat", _
      "Falkland Islands", "Niue", "Tokelau", "Holy See", "Rep. of Moldova", "Macedonia", "Neth. Antilles", "EU", "Asia n.i.e.")

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'We use the ActiveSheet but you can replace this with
    'Sheets("MySheet")if you want
    With ActiveSheet

        'We select the sheet so we can change the window view
        .Select

        'If you are in Page Break Preview Or Page Layout view go
        'back to normal view, we do this for speed
        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

        'Turn off Page Breaks, we do this for speed
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False

        'Set the first and last row to loop through
        Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
        Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

        'We loop from Lastrow to Firstrow (bottom to top)
        For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

            'We check the values in the A column in this example
            With .Cells(Lrow, "J")

                If Not IsError(.Value) Then

                    If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Value, LessPop, 0)) Then
                        .EntireRow.Delete
                    End If
                    'This will delete each row with the countries written above
                    'in Column A, case sensitive.

                End If

            End With

        Next Lrow

    End With

    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub
```